# change color of ul li ul li while hovering

Tags: html, css

I want to change color of the tags `li ul li` but it doesn't change with the given html amd css.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="s">
    <li>
        <ul>#1
            <li>Hello</li>
             <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>#2
            <li>Hello</li>
             <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.s li ul li{
    color:red;
    list-style:none;

}
.s li {
list-style:none;  
}
.s li ul{
    color:green;
}
.s li ul:hover  .s li ul li{
color:black;
}
```

I have created a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2SUn9/)**

What do I need to add or change to make the color change on hovering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No element matches `.s li ul:hover  .s li ul li`

The last CSS rule should be

```
.s li ul:hover li{
    color:black;
}
```

Edit: jQuery's way to do it needs a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event, but the `hover` method covers both.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".s li ul" ).hover(
        function() {
   $('li', this ).css('color','black' );
  }, function() {
     $('li', this ).css('color','red' );
  }); 
});
```

Comment: *Does the happy dance*

Comment: Btw, do u know how to make jquery version of this? :D

Comment: I added the jQuery way to do it

Comment: Man u are awesome, can i have ur fb if i have more questons? I can help u with php :)

Comment: hehehe, I rather not commit to help anyone outside S.O. last time I had my inbox full with a random guy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55932/discussion-between-crion-and-amenadiel).

Answer (score 0):

```
.s li ul:hover,
.s li ul li:hover {
     color:black;
}
```

You miss the **,** to separate the two **selector** and forget **:hover** on the second.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your hover css like this you forgot the last li**

```
   .s li ul li:hover{
      color:black;
    }
```